# How to access the team structure of AX database from .net web application?

Tags: c#, sql-server, axapta

I need to access the team structure of the company using .net web application, which is stored in AX database. As I have to specify user privileges based on their department and role .

I have searched for it, most of them saying that I have to use business connector. But my question is can I connect the AX's database with out installing business connector? If so, then what is the connection string?

Thanks

Comment: The connection string depends on your SQL server version, what authentication you use, ... You can access it like a regular SQL server database.

Answer (score 1):

When necessary handling /access data, consider **strongly** the use of **Services/ AIF or .NET Business Connector**. that way you keep access logic data / permissions and business rules inside AX. (Manipulate data directly into the AX database is usually a bad idea)

However, if your need is just some simple data access, **read only**, you can create *Views* within the AX and access this Views by another application using SQL Server Connection Strings (consider these "views/queries" the data permissions "joins/ranges")

See this link:

**https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa877498.aspx**

I hope this helps!

Regards,

Rodolfo Recalde